# Bluring a dynamic background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know a few methods to blur images - the `Apple class`(`ApplyLightEffect`) , and the `CIFilter` , but they are all takes `UIImage` and create a blur.

I need to simply create some layer above images that are moving, and blur this layer so everything behind is blur. the blur effect should be very gentle.

How would i get that in a simple way ? are there more ways to apply similar effects to blur that i can check ? (which are dynamic )

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this iOS Framework:

- https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Instead of instantiating your view like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Import FXBlurView and do this:

```
FXBlurView *blurredView = [[FXBlurView alloc] init];
```

You can also set some custom parameters:

```
[blurredView setBlurRadius:30]; //Sets radius of blur
[blurredView setDynamic:NO]; //Disables whether the blur updates in real time.
[blurredView setBlurEnables:YES]; //Enables/disables the blur.
[blurredView setTintColor:nil]; //Set to nil to get rid of the blue glow from the default iOS tint color.
```

That should do it.

Comment: oh, thats perfect ! much better than apple class  !

Comment: @user1994291 Be sure to check performance on all device types you intend to target. I've found this to be too slow on older devices in real time mode